# Cannot show ArrayList from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, ms-access, servlets, intellij-idea

I am using servlet and jsp to show Access database.

MainDatabase.java

```
    public class MainDatabase
    {
        private int proId;
        private String proName;
        private String proQuantity;
        private String proPrice;

        public MainDatabase()
        {
            this.proId = 0;
            this.proName = "";
            this.proQuantity = "";
            this.proPrice = "";
        }

        public int getProId() {
            return proId;
        }

        public void setProId(int proId) {
            this.proId = proId;
        }

        public String getProName() {
            return proName;
        }

        public void setProName(String proName) {
            this.proName = proName;
        }

        public String getProQuantity() {
            return proQuantity;
        }

        public void setProQuantity(String proQuantity) {
            this.proQuantity = proQuantity;
        }

        public String getProPrice() {
            return proPrice;
        }

        public void setProPrice(String proPrice) {
            this.proPrice = proPrice;
        }
    }
```

MainDatabaseUtil.java

```
    import org.hsqldb.Database;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;


    public class MainDatabaseUtil
    {
        public static List<MainDatabase> getMainDB() throws Exception
        {
            List<MainDatabase> mainDatabases = null;
            JSONArray payload = null;
            try
            {
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:\\study_materials\\Java\\Resources\\Database\\smsDemo.accdb");
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * from Database");

                stmt.close();
                conn.close();

                mainDatabases = new ArrayList<>();

                //payload = new JSONArray();

                if(rs != null)
                {
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        MainDatabase proDB = new MainDatabase();
                        proDB.setProId(rs.getInt("ID"));
                        proDB.setProName(rs.getString("ProName"));
                        proDB.setProQuantity(rs.getString("Quantity"));
                        proDB.setProPrice(rs.getString("Price"));

                        mainDatabases.add(proDB);
                    }
                }

                return mainDatabases;
                //return payload;
            }

            catch(Exception el)
            {
                return mainDatabases;
            }
        }
    }
```

MainDatabaseServlet.java

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
    import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
    import javax.servlet.*;

    @WebServlet("/MainDatabaseServlet")

    public class MainDatabaseServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public MainDatabaseServlet()
        {
            super();
        }

        public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            try
            {
                List<MainDatabase> mainDatabases = MainDatabaseUtil.getMainDB();
                request.setAttribute("main_list", mainDatabases);
                RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/MainDatabaseView.jsp");
                dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            }
            catch (Exception el)
            {
                el.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            doGet(request, response);
        }
    }
```

MainDatabaseView.jsp

```
    <%--
      Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
      User: Xenon
      Date: 11/15/2018
      Time: 9:15 PM
      To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
    --%>
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ page import ="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <%@ page import ="java.util.List"%>

    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Main Database</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Student Table Demo</h2><br>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <table border="1">

            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>QUANTITY</th>
                <th>PRICE</th>
            </tr>

            <c:forEach var="tempData" items="${main_list}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${tempData.proId}</td>
                    <td>${tempData.proName}</td>
                    <td>${tempData.proQuantity}</td>
                    <td>${tempData.proPrice}</td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I am using IntelliJ Idea. It's showing that in MainDatabaseView.jsp, it cannot resolve variable main_list.

Current Output: Its showing table column name but no data in it.

[image]

Expected output should be showing database value in table view when the program is run.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: Mihir, check my answer and let us know

Comment: how exactly are you going to the jsp? are you trying to access it directly or through the servlet?

Comment: I am accessing jsp from Servlet. I am using RequestDispatcher in MainDatabaseServlet.java file.

Answer (score 1):

Call `stmt.close();` and `conn.close();` after retrieving the values from the `ResultSet`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

> When you are finished using a Statement, call the method Statement.close to immediately release the resources it is using. When you call this method, its ResultSet objects are closed.

If you close the statement before retrieving the result set, the result set will no longer have any reference to the data.

Comment: Thanks. After the update, it still doesn't give the expected output.

Comment: Can you display what it shows? I'm think I'm confused by "Its showing table column name but data in it."

Comment: I have put output image in question, please check.